# Trouble Defining a LaTeX Command

Tags: tables, macros

I am trying to define a table of direct sums of `{\chi_i}`in LaTeX, meaning that the entries will be things of the form: `5 \chi_2 \bigoplus \chi_4 \bigoplus 2 \chi_7` for given data like  `{{1,0},{2,5},{3,0},{4,1},{5,0},{6,0},{7,2}}` that tells you how many copies of each `\chi_i` we want for a given entry. How I wrote the data is just an example. I can format the data in whatever the most convenient form happens to be.

In order to avoid hardcoding in each entry of the table, I'm trying to define a new command in LaTeX, either via `\newcommand` or `\def`, that will take in such data and return it in the form of a direct sum as written above, but I'm a bit new to it and don't know how I should go about creating a command with what will be a variable number of arguments, since not each direct sum can be written with just three terms. The fact that `\newcommand` and `\def` take in a fixed number of arguments make me think that I should not be using them for this task. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT:

More accurately, the data concerning the coefficients of the sum is going to look like `{5,2,7,8,2,0,0,1,3}` where this is meant to be read as `5 \chi_1 \bigoplus 2 \chi_2 \bigoplus \ldot \bigoplus 3 \chi_9` where the sequence is always going to be a fixed size. It should also be the case that the terms with zeros should not show up in the sum.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Updated for new format:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\zz#1{{\@for\tmp:=#1\do{\expandafter\zzz\tmp\relax}}}
\def\zzz#1,#2\relax{\zzsep#1\chi_{#2}}
\def\zzsep{\def\zzsep{\bigoplus}}

\def\yy#1{{\count@\z@
\@for\tmp:=#1\do{\advance\count@\@ne
\ifnum\tmp=\z@\else\zzsep\tmp\chi_{\the\count@}\fi}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\[
 \zz{{1,0},{2,5},{3,0},{4,1},{5,0},{6,0},{7,2}}
\]

\[
\yy{5,2,7,8,2,0,0,1,3} 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I am surprised to do this would require defining three commands though. It seems like something that should not be too difficult.

Comment: It doesn't have to use three it was just easier that way, basically because of the`,` syntax, you need one to loop through the outer comma list then another to split up the inner comma pair and the zzsep is just an easy way of avoiding putting the oplus separator before the first. three lines of code to implement a loop, splitting a pair and inserting a separator doesn't seem much to me:-)

Comment: Would you please have a look at my edit?

Comment: @aentropy updated uses 2 macros now not 3 (I hope to steal that tick off egreg:-)

Comment: Gave you the answer back cause this was the one I ended up using, I couldn't get LaTeX 3 to install on my computer to use egreg's solution. Would you happen to know what's wrong with the following? \def\clebschtable#1{\hline\@for\tmpi:=#1\do{$\chi$\@for\tmpj:=\tmpi\do{~HERE~$\‌​chisum{\tmpj}$~THERE~}\\}} I'm trying to put in a \ttand right where it says ~HERE~, but whenever I do I get an "! Undefined control sequence." on \tmpj. For some reason I can put it ~THERE~ without any error, but it's not what I want. TeX logic is really confusing the heck out of me.

Comment: @aentropy you can't use that kind of loop in a table as each cell is a local group so as soon as you do `\\ ` the group ends and all the current state of the loop is discarded.

Answer (score 11):

This code is longer than David's, but way more modern and fashionable, as it uses LaTeX3 functions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\chisum}{m} % a homage to John Wayne
 {
  \aentropy_chisum:n { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \aentropy_chisum:n #1
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_aentropy_chisum_seq
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \aentropy_add_summand:n { ##1 }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_aentropy_chisum_seq { \oplus }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \aentropy_add_summand:n #1
 {
  \__aentropy_add_summand:w #1 \q_stop
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__aentropy_add_summand:w #1 , #2 \q_stop
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 = 1 }
   {% if the number of summands is 1, we don't show it
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_aentropy_chisum_seq { \chi\c_math_subscript_token{#2} }
   }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_aentropy_chisum_seq { #1\chi\c_math_subscript_token{#2} }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\chisum{{1,0},{2,5},{3,0},{4,1},{5,0},{6,0},{7,2}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is just the same: we process the comma separated list and split each item into two components (coefficient and index); we store the built summand in a sequence and then deliver it separating its items with `\oplus`.

---

In order to comply with the second specification, some adaptations must be made.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\chisum}{m} % a homage to John Wayne
 {
  \aentropy_chisum:n { #1 }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_aentropy_chisum_seq
\int_new:N \l_aentropy_chisum_index_int
\cs_new_protected:Npn \aentropy_chisum:n #1
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_aentropy_chisum_seq
  \int_zero:N \l_aentropy_chisum_index_int
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \int_incr:N \l_aentropy_chisum_index_int
    \aentropy_add_summand:n { ##1 }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_aentropy_chisum_seq { \oplus }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \aentropy_add_summand:n #1
 {
  \int_compare:nF { #1 = 0 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_aentropy_chisum_seq
     {
      \int_compare:nF { #1 = 1 } { #1 }
      \exp_not:n { \chi }
      \c_math_subscript_token
      { \int_to_arabic:n { \l_aentropy_chisum_index_int } }
     }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\chisum{5,2,7,8,2,0,0,1,3}$

\end{document}
```

Note that `\exp_not:n { \chi }` is not really necessary, because `\chi` is not expandable; but you might want to change the symbol and so it's better to be safe than sorry.

Zero terms are omitted, one terms are printed without the coefficient 1.

[image]

With a different definition of `\aentropy_add_summand:n` you can also use symbolic coefficients. Each item will be compared to the string `0` and, in this case, no summand will be added; otherwise, the item is compared to `1` and, in this case, no coefficient is added.

```
\cs_new:Npn \aentropy_add_summand:n #1
 {
  \str_if_eq:nnF { #1 } { 0 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l_aentropy_chisum_seq
     {
      \str_if_eq:nnF { #1 } { 1 } { #1 }
      \exp_not:n { \chi }
      \c_math_subscript_token
      { \int_to_arabic:n { \l_aentropy_chisum_index_int } }
     }
   }
 }
```

Try with

```
$\chisum{5,2,7,8,2,0,0,1,3}$

$\chisum{a,b,2,0,0,0,0,1,3}$
```

and you'll get

[image]

Comment: I was expecting an L3 list from you:-) (+1 for predictability:-)

Comment: Would you please have a look at my edit?